# CONVERT_IMPLICIT converts my varchar field and not my string constant in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am trying to optimize a where clause. I read that CONVERT_IMPLICIT can slow things down.

I have a where clause that tests to see if the state (field strTate) is in a list of state abbreviations. The state field is varchar(30). The where clause was:

```
@State IN ('NY', 'PR', 'VI', 'MAA', 'RI', 'NH', 'ME', 'VT', 'CT', 'NJ', 'AE')
```

The execution plan showed each of these string constants as nvarchars, like N'NY'. 
It then performed this for each abbreviation:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(3), <dbname>.[dbo].[TblAddress].[strState],0)=N'NY'
```

I read that because of type precedence, a varchar will be implicitly converted into an nvarchar, not the other way around. But I figure that converting the constant expression once instead of the column expression a million times is faster, so I try this:

```
@State IN (
cast('NY' as varchar(30)), 
cast('PR' as varchar(30)), 
cast('VI' as varchar(30)), 
cast('MA' as varchar(30)), 
cast('RI' as varchar(30)), 
cast('NH' as varchar(30)), 
cast('ME' as varchar(30)), 
cast('VT' as varchar(30)), 
cast('CT' as varchar(30)), 
cast('NJ' as varchar(30)), 
cast('AE' as varchar(30)) 
)
```

The execution plan is the same. I see no mention of my casts, and it still converts the field to nvarchar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you casting a 2 character string as `varchar(30)`?

Comment: You aren't comparing against the column. What is the datatype of `@State`?

Comment: The @state parameter resolves to the strState field, which is varchar(30). Because varchar is lower precedence than nvarchar, SQL optimizer is converting millions of rows' strState values to nvarchar(3) for the comparison when what I want is to convert the string constant once before the comparison and save time.

Comment: What is your full query? `@State IN ('NY', 'PR', 'VI', 'MAA', 'RI', 'NH', 'ME', 'VT', 'CT', 'NJ', 'AE')` doesn't involve any comparison with the column at all.

Comment: ampersand State is a parameter to an inline table valued function. The function is called with strState as the parameter, so where you see ampersand State, assume strState. The full query is like ten pages long. You don't want to see it.

Comment: We need to see more of it because it is totally unclear what you are doing. Posting code that compares **a parameter** with `in` and telling us to pretend it is a column is nonsensical. If you were actually doing `strState IN ('NY', 'PR', 'VI', 'MAA', 'RI', 'NH', 'ME', 'VT', 'CT', 'NJ', 'AE')` against a `varchar` column there wouldn't be any implicit casts. So we need to see what you are *actually* doing.

Comment: @Martin Smith, I took your comment at face value, and sure enough, it is nonsense to pretend a parameter is the same as a column. While the column being passed into the procedure is varchar, the formal parameter was defined to be nvarchar! Smoking gun, sheepish coder...

Answer (score 0):

To write a Unicode constant, use N prefix, e.g., N'NY' or if you want to go with converting than convert to nvarchar(3) as opposed to varchar. This will mean there won't be any cast by SQL Server.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the state abbreviation constants to be unicode, but it makes them unicode anyway. My data column is varchar(30) and I am trying to make the constants varchar(30) too but it won't let me. If the constants are unicode then it has to turn the strState column into unicode to perform the comparison, which is what I am trying to avoid. A better solution would be changing the data type of strName to nvarchar, but the database schema is untouchable; it is the client's database.